# How to make an event happen after a javascript alert in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have this line of code:

```
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('You need to be logged in in order to proceed to checkout. You will now be transfered to the Login page.')", true);
```

And I want to be transfered to the a page using Response.Redirect() after I click on "OK" in the alert pop-up message. How can I do it?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Since you are using javascript to show the user the alert message - you could add a little more javascript to trigger a redirect. You could also achieve that by using javascript to trigger a postback to your page and then handle the redirect on the server.

Comment: You could do it from javascript with `location = '..whatever url...';` instead of server-side redirect.